# How can I rename a variable to be part of an array?

Tags: android, android-studio, refactoring, rename

I've written my code to include a variable called `rectangleX`, but now I'd like to have multiple similar variables, so I want to rename the variable to `rectangleX[0]`. However, when I go to refactor, then rename, I get the error 'Inserted identifier is not valid'. How can I get around this?

Comment: You could rename it `rectangleX_0`

Comment: Showing more of the altered source code would make it easier to understand the source of the error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to change a single variable into an array.  I'd suggest separating it out, or simply add your rectagleX variables directly to the List.

```
List<String> rectangleList= new ArrayList<String>();
rectangleList.add(rectangleXVar1);
rectangleList.add(rectangleXVar2);
rectangleList.add(rectangleXVar3);
rectangleList.add(rectangleXVar4);

for(int i=0;i<rectangleList.length;i++) {
    System.out.println(rectangleList[i]);
}
```